# why magnific popup ajax box closes if clicked on content

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

Please Please Please help me.. I have been trying to get the magnific popup ajax box to show login form. It seems that form appears but as soon as I click anywhere in form or ajax body, it disappears. below is the code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
 type: 'ajax',
 alignTop: false,
 closeOnContentClick: false,
 overflowY: 'scroll'
 });
 });

<a class=".ajax-popup-link" href="result.php">try me</a><br>
```

Below is the php that I look to load in ajax box. This is not the complete one

```
 Email:<div class="field_container">Password:</label>
    <input type='password' name='cust_password' id='password'  maxlength="12" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; /></div>

   <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Login' />
```

Answer (score 15):

This is the old thread but for all the future readers: to fix this, there has to be only one root element in the html that comes out from the ajax call:

As per documentation:

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#ajax_type

So in your ajax call you should return something like this:

```
<div>    
    ...your html content 
</div>
```

and your popup will no longer close itself on content click.

Comment: Weird stuff. Had one root element with a preceding HTML comment. Removed comment => works. Why not handle this internally by creating a wrapper dynamically instead of breaking in obscure ways is beyond me.

Comment: It helps. Thanks. I had an html <!-- --> comment above root div and it caused the break of close as well

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, solved it by using:

```
modal:true,
```

instead of:

```
closeOnContentClick: false,
```

Comment: Or, set `closeOnBgClick: false` instead of `modal:true` if you still want the close button and escape key (see http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#options)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem removing HTML and BODY tags in result.php.