# How to prevent close

Tags: magnific-popup

I've got some form controls in my popup, and would like to prevent the user from closing it if the form is invalid.

I tried this just as a test, but the popup still closes when the user clicks the close button, etc.

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: '#topic'
            },
            type: 'inline',
            removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
            mainClass: 'mfp-3d-unfold',
            closeMarkup: '<button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close"></button>',
            midClick: true, // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
            callbacks: {
                beforeClose: function () {
                    // Callback available since v0.9.0
                    return false;
                },
                close: function () {
                    // Will fire when popup is closed
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs, if you add `closeOnContentClick: false` as an option, the window shouldn't close.

```
magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: '#topic'
            },
            type: 'inline',
            closeOnContentClick: false,
            removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
            mainClass: 'mfp-3d-unfold',
            closeMarkup: '<button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close"></button>',
            midClick: true
        });
```

However, I've been trying to get an ajax window to not close when there's a click inside it (a form) and *adding this option doesn't work at all* (it may well work for inline though). The only way I've been able to get it to work so far is by adding a class of `mfp-prevent-close` to all of the child nodes within the popup (eg all of the form input fields, the surrounding fieldset etc).

Hope this helps anyway :)

Comment: I just found this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215477/why-magnific-popup-ajax-box-closes-if-clicked-on-content - looks like you could try adding modal:true instead of closeOnContentClick:false

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/463)

You need to replace the following line of the code

```
// if click is outside the content
if( (target !== mfp.content[0] && !$.contains(mfp.content[0], target)) ) {
```

with

```
// if click is outside the content
if( (target !== mfp.content[0] && !$.contains(mfp.content[0].parentElement, target)) ) {
```

It fixed the problem for me.